# Prevent browsers from loading specific page ever

Tags: windows-10, internet

Is there any way to force Windows 10 to **never** open a certain webpage?

While surfing the web, I am sometimes sent to a page that says my hard drive is about to be erased unless I call a phone number. Obviously, this is crap. I have to kill the browser from the Task Manager and I lose all my tabs. So is there any way to force windows 10 to never open up that page?

TIA,
paul

Comment: You do realize that you block one page and the other 1,000,000,000 websites that serve the same script/image will not be blocked right?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Just a suggestion, but Firefox with the No Script and uBlock Origin plugins should do a good job preventing sites for taking your browser hostage like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could point that page to 127.0.0.1 in %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

Alternative 1:

If you are connecting to the internet using an router with good capabilities then you could blacklist the site from the router configuration.

Alternative 2 (IMHO best):

Install ublock origin in your browser. It's an simple option and rules will auto update. You can also create your own rules.

Comment: Method 1 does not work. HOSTS file works on domains, not pages.

Answer (score 0):

Without third-party apps, you can't.

In Firefox and Chrome, you can install the uBlock Origin extension and tell it to block that web page. In Edge, you only have AdBlock Plus which doesn't quite cut it.

To do it system-wide, COMODO Internet Security has a web filtering feature that can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding it to "unsecure" pages via:
Control panel > Internet Options > Security tab > Restricted sites.

On the other hand, this might be fixing a symtpom and not the cause. I'd also suggest a malware check.

Comment: Even with malware on the system, Google Chrome and some other browsers allow websites to prevent browsers from closing. It's never a bad idea to do a malware check from time to time, but I'd guess this isn't the case here.